# How to select all elements, except one and all its children using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

With the following HTML, how can I select all divs at parent level only, except div with attribute - `class="first"` and its children using JavaScript?

In other words, after calling a query I want to get an array with these divs: `class="all"`, `class="second"` and `class="third"`.

```
<div class="all">
    <div class="header">All</div>
    <div class="cell-1"></div>
    <div class="cell-2"></div>
    <div class="cell-3"></div>
    <div class="cell-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="first">
    <div class="header">First</div>
    <div class="cell-1"></div>
    <div class="cell-2"></div>
    <div class="cell-3"></div>
    <div class="cell-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="second">
    <div class="header">Second</div>
    <div class="cell-1"></div>
    <div class="cell-2"></div>
    <div class="cell-3"></div>
    <div class="cell-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="third">
    <div class="header">Third</div>
    <div class="cell-1"></div>
    <div class="cell-2"></div>
    <div class="cell-3"></div>
    <div class="cell-4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

These divs are children of some container (`body` at least, if not something more immediate). So you can use a selector with a [child combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) and a [`:not`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) clause for the `.first` element you don't want:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("body > div:not(.first)");
```

Of course, if `body` isn't their container, replace that with a selector for the element that is.

Example:

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("body > div:not(.first)");
console.log("matching elements: " + divs.length);
Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function(div, index) {
  console.log(index + ": " + div.className);
});
```

```html
<div class="all">
  <div class="header">All</div>
  <div class="cell-1"></div>
  <div class="cell-2"></div>
  <div class="cell-3"></div>
  <div class="cell-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="first">
  <div class="header">First</div>
  <div class="cell-1"></div>
  <div class="cell-2"></div>
  <div class="cell-3"></div>
  <div class="cell-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="second">
  <div class="header">Second</div>
  <div class="cell-1"></div>
  <div class="cell-2"></div>
  <div class="cell-3"></div>
  <div class="cell-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="third">
  <div class="header">Third</div>
  <div class="cell-1"></div>
  <div class="cell-2"></div>
  <div class="cell-3"></div>
  <div class="cell-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Genuine question: is the container really needed? `document.querySelectorAll("div:not(.first)")` seems to work as weel.

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado: That matches all the inner divs along with the outer divs. Not sure the asker wants such a massive collection of elements. Plus it also matches the children of .first - which presumably the asker does *not* want.

Comment: Yes, I asked this because I believe that *this* (selecting all their children) is what he/she wants...  anyway, it's not clear.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: From the question: *"I want to get an array with these divs: class="all", class="second" and class="third"."* That suggests just the three are desired.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, you're correct. Besides that, it matches all children of `.first`, as @BoltClock said, and that's definitely not what OP wants.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to build your [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) using the direct child combinator and the negation pseudo-class.

Vanilla JavaScript:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("body > div:not(.first)");
```

jQuery:

```
var divs = $("body > div:not(.first)");
```

In the example above I'm assuming these divs are direct children of the `body` element, but if they aren't you can use the `id` or `class` of their parent instead:

```
<div id="container">
   //divs here
</div>
```

would be:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#container > div:not(.first)");
```

and

```
<div class="container">
   //divs here
</div>
```

would be:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".container > div:not(.first)");
```

The direct child combinator `>` only selects elements that meet criteria of the second selector (`div` for all div elements) and are only one level below the first selector (`body` for the body, `#container` and `.container` for the container div).  Other elements additional levels below the first selector are ignored (e.g. `<div class="header">Third</div>` etc.).

The negation pseudo-class takes a simple selector as an argument (in this case `.first`) and excludes elements matching that selector from the results.

You can see a demonstration here: http://jsbin.com/puqosimigu/edit?html,js,console